# How to troubleshoot Django web app connection to Teradata?

Tags: django, database-connection, gunicorn, nginx-config, unixodbc

Can anyone please help me to troubleshoot this? A new Unix server is setup as test environment for an existing production django web app/server. On the test server I can pull data using bteq, but the web app doesn't (i.e. the json data doesn't populate. Everything else looks fine). All the configuration/settings are the same as the production server.

I tried below steps in the production server and it returned with data, but in the test server I got the error.

```
python manage.py shell
>>> from project_web.shared_functions import teradata_con
>>> import json
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> sql = """select distinct rgn_num, rgn_nm from RLDMPROD.SITE_HIER;"""
>>> pd.read_sql(sql, teradata_con())
```

`` Error: python: libltdl/ltdl.c:1197: try_dlopen: Assertion `filename && *filename' failed.
Aborted (core dumped) ``

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace?  To debug, can you dump the `sql` resultset from your query to the to see if it's returning anything?

Comment: `>>> pd.read_sql(sql, teradata_con())
  RGN_NUM              RGN_NM
0    0004    Sales Org Quebec
1    0002      Sales Org West
2    0005  Sales Org Atlantic
3    0001  Sales Org National
4    0003   Sales Org Ontario`

Comment: The above is the data returned. The Error I posted there is all I got from my screen. I believe it's complete stacktrace. Or can you show me how to view it please? Thank you!

Comment: Hmm...if it's returning data I'm not sure.  It may be a driver / environment issue.  See this link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unixodbc/+bug/362603

Comment: after I **activate virtualenv**, `pyodbc.drivers()` return empty. Even though `odbcinst -j` returns the same drivers as the production server.